# Compositing: Ho to scale compositing results to different image sizes?

Tags: image, compositing-nodes

I have a compositing and would like to save the image result to individual files by using different image sizes.

Currently I only know the end size of an composting result is based in the scene render size.

But is there a way to scale the image and save it with the new size?

This would safe me time.

Thanx